# Have SolR limit number of hits per file

Tags: java, lucene, solr

I have a SolR index where each record is a page from a file. So for every record we have the full text, the page number and the file ID.

When we do a search, often a single file will overwhelm the results as it contains the search term repeatedly.

What I would like to do is to have the search query only return a maximum of two hits per document and then offer the user a "see more hits from this document" which would do another, more limited query. I.e. similar to how Google will only show you a handful of results from any given domain, with the option of seeing more from each.

Is there anyway to structure a SolR query to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Which solr version are you using? If it's 4.0 (i.e. nightly), then you can use [collapsing](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FieldCollapsing) on the filename field.

Comment: SolR 1.4.1 (which I believe is the most recent stable release).

Comment: @Kris: Check the field collapsing issue in JIRA, it has a patch 1.4.1: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-236